# NextJs: Calling setInterval with a variable for time inside of a React useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, setinterval, use-effect

I have a function called fetchData. It's purpose is to retrieve data based on an api endpoint argument and update that data based on an interval argument.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const fetchData = (endpoint, interval) => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const innerFetchData = async () => {
      fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => data)
        .then((moreData) => setJsonData(moreData))
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    };

    innerFetchData();

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      innerFetchData();
    }, interval);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return jsonData;
};
```

I'm importing it and using it in one of my react components

```
const data = fetchData('/api/CustomerWorkspace', 5000);
```

What is going wrong is that I don't think it's reading the interval argument correctly, when I run it, it infinitely calls the api maybe 50 times per second. If i hard code the interval time on the timer inside of fetchData, it works correctly. Can you please help me figure out how I can pass in a interval variable so I can reuse fetchData across different components? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `useInterval`, a custom hook that handles some weirdness with this browser API and React.

Short: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-interval

Full explanation: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Demo applyed:

```js
// file: useInterval.js
export const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
};

// your file
// import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react"
// import { useInterval } from "./useInterval"
export const fetchData = (endpoint, interval) => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(null);
  
  const innerFetchData = useCallback(
    // if you gonna use `.then` you don't need the async in here tho
    async () => {
      fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => data)
        .then((moreData) => setJsonData(moreData))
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    },
    [endpoint]
  );

  // runs once
  useEffect(() => {
    innerFetchData();
  }, []);
  
  // runs every `interval`
  useInterval(() => {
    innerFetchData();
  }, interval);

  return jsonData;
};
```

And you can also turn this fetchData function in a hook itself if you want, just call it `useFetchData` and the usage is the same. Don't change anything I think, but imo its more fancy xP

Answer (score 0):

if you call `innerFetchData();` only inside setInterval then it would work fine. You are calling `innerFetchData()` twice inside useEffect

Comment: I can't exactly see why would that, but it's indeed a weird setup. Anyway, just removing it wouldn't exactly fix, because now it runs only in intervals, so, don't run in first render. You accidentally removed an important behaviour of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `innerFetchData()`, it set state via `setJsonData` . That triggers a rerender, causing useEffect to remove the interval you've already set and create a new one immediately. So your interval is probably set correctly, but it's being cleared on every request.

What you should do is storing the timer in a `useRef`. That will help it persist throughout the component's lifecycles.